# Работа с COM-объектом в c++ созданном в c#

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, com

Решил изучить работу com-объектов. Сделал по примеру код d c#

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace COM_test
{
    [Guid("7FAFBE67-24F0-44F9-8C0C-10F795C4E838")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
    public interface ICalculator
    {
        int Sum(int a, int b);
    }

    [Guid("9A946209-4EF3-47BD-B4C7-8B1F2EFFCF53")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    public class Calculator : ICalculator
    {
        public int Sum(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
    }
}
```

Вроде регистрируется в системе и появляется в списке.
Как теперь его использовать в c++?
Пробовал и так `//#include <COM_test.tlb"> и так`  //#import COM_test.tlb`
И почему-то иногда в visual studio бывает так, что в ссылках не выводятся com-объекты. Что я делаю не так? Если можно, то пример с кодом c++ был-бы кстати

Comment: Ну по-хорошему вам необходимо написать (сгенерировать) соотв. заголовочный файл а потом как обычно - `CoCreateInstance`

Comment: @user7860670,а можно поподробней, а лучше с примером, если не в тягость. где-то натыкался в гугле на CoCreateInstance, но внятное объяснение так и не нашел?  и почему com библиотеки не всегда появляются при вызове меню оных?

Comment: т.е. как это "не нашел внятное объяснение"? это же одна из самых основных функций COM, которой обычно создаются экземпляры класса. Что там у вас не появляется?

Comment: @user7860670, в меню "Добавить ссылку..." не появлялись библиотеки - с этим справился, просто забыл включить поддержку CLR для с++.

Comment: @user7860670, по поводу самой библиотеки - если использую //#import <COM_test.tlb">, то ругается, что нет файла COM_test с расширением TLH

Comment: Вам стоит определиться, вы хотите использовать из С++ или из С++-cli.

Comment: @user7860670, если использую //#include <COM_test.tlb">, то вроде не ругается, но в этом случае не знаю что делать

Comment: @user7860670, мне, как человеку не особо разбирающемуся в крестах это ни о чем не говорит. в чем различие C++ и C++/CLI?

Comment: с++-cli - это отдельный С++-подобный язык с поддержкой CLR (для которого на so отдельный тег). *"не особо разбирающемуся в крестах"* - ну тогда вам сначала стоит разобраться, а уже затем пытаться работать с COM... а то будете спотыкаться и отстреливать себе ноги и другие конечности на каждом шагу

Comment: @user7860670, вон оно что... Вообще: у меня пока нет времени разбираться в крестах. Хотелось-бы просто на каком-нибудь примере увидеть как мой com-объект, написанный на c#, будет работать на на другом языке

Comment: ну тогда достаточно будет поглядеть на любой пример использования CoCreateInstance, например https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/creating-an-object-in-com - только там будет GUID вашего класса и указатель на ваш интерфейс. COM хорош тем, что позволяет единообразно использовать интерфейсы из разных языков

Comment: @user7860670, спасибо. попробую